# Install ESXi locally

Tags: esxi

I'd like to be able to boot a PC from an ESXi install CD, instead of installing ESXi on a host PC and then configuring each PC from there,

I'd like to configure the PC locally and install the OS locally.

In the configuration the sort of things that may be configured is BIOS settings, time zone, keyboard, network, SATA/IDE/RAID, etc

I have seen a PC update the version of ESXi by booting from the ESXi CD, and I have seen ESXi run server or workstation OS's too.

Is this Possible?

Comment: Rather install esxi on a 8G flash drive, boot PC from there and build your vm's that way. Just seem more modern and better.

Comment: @Rudolph ok, flash drive then, since the CD drive will be needed for the OS CD anyhow but is it possible?

Comment: @Rudolph I counted the ESXi iso (with network drivers included) with rufus however when I boot into ESXi It still complains that it cannot find the network card or drivers.

Comment: Haven't encountered that before. Maybe get a different NIC?

Comment: yeah, Ill have to anyhow as the virtual-ized OS does not work with my NIC